# Vim - spf13, signs explanation (exclamation mark, plus sign) and warning message clarification

Tags: python, vim

Running vim on spf13 configuration and I have the following questions:

In a python file, after executing PymodeLintAuto, several lines have been split to comply with pep8, however an exclamation mark is next to one of these lines and a plus sign next to its following line, as shown in the picture:

[image: Vim signs in a Python file]

The same signs can be found on my .vimrc.local file scattered around, but a warning appears at the right bottom line of the status line:

[image: Vim signs in a configuration file]

What is the meaning of the `!` and `+` signs, and how could I correct my code in order to make the warnings disappear?

I persume that the `+` sign indicates that this line was added relative to the previous version of the file. Should the `!` sign indicate that this line included the error that was corrected?

The `! trailing[164]` message indicates that the `!` sign is next to the 164 lines with trailing white space for instance? (line 37, however, does not have such trailing whitespace)

**Illuminating Details:**

The modules involved are:

- vim-airline
- vim-signify

Finally, the exclamation mark on the side has nothing to do with the exclamation mark at the bottom right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!` means that the line was changed.

`+` means that the line was added.

You probably have a plugin like signify or some variant installed as part of that stupid SPF13 distribution but you don't know about it because you abdicated all control of your config to some random guy on the internet. Look at your `~/.vim` directory or spf13's doc to find the exact cause.

You should jump on this opportunity to drop that distribution and do *your* configuration *yourself*.

Comment: +1 Getting a bit grumpy in our old days are we? <g> I agree that there's definitely a ROI doing your configuration yourself. I learned a lot from doing it *(and still counting)* but it takes effort nonetheless. Effort you, at first, can't be sure of if it's effort well spend or just a waste of time. I find myself in a similar position right now trying to decide wether I should dive into Eclipse or not. For now I am exactly using it like OP seems to have picked up vim: trying to get the job done with whatever config my co-workers use but I couldn't care less about the finer details.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, I was *born* grumpy.

Comment: @rara_tiru, the answer to your question about `! trailing[164]` is in essence the same as for the signs: one of your plugins is doing that but you don't know which one because you *"lay this worrying on someone more experienced"*. It's probably whatever fancy statusline plugin that comes with your distribution, who knows? It's *your* config and *you* are supposed to be the one in charge. Letting someone do the low-level stuff for you is one (silly, IMO) thing but, seriously, not reading the doc/changelog of what you install is just irresponsible. And probably the cause of your earlier issue.

Comment: @rara_tiru, no because I don't use a fancy statusline plugin. Did you even try to find out what fancy statusline plugin you use and what options are set for it? Or are you really asking us to do that for you?

Comment: @romaini Thank you for your help. I very much admire vim's philosophy, supporting *as less typing as possible*. This is why I enjoy putting myself in the shoes of co-workers who contribute -*in a positive manner*- to the community and relish learning on that basis. I might be wrong but even if this is the case, it will prove to be one more lesson to appreciate. "Think positive".